# How do you cite a book classified under two editions?

Tags: citations

In a works cited page in MLA format, when citing a book part of the citation is, for example,

> Stewart, James. *Calculus: Early Transcendentals*. [EDITION] ed. Belmont: Brooks/Cole, 2009. Print.

This calculus textbook is the AP edition of the Sixth edition of the textbook. Should *[EDITION]* be written as "AP ed. Sixth ed."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Library of Congress has another edition and cite it as: "[7th ed., alternate ed.](https://lccn.loc.gov/2012359139)".

Without knowing how the main title page (as a librarian that's the most important source for cataloging a book) or other parts of the book look like, I'd say it is the 6th ed. of the AP ed.: "6th. ed, AP ed.".

I recommend going to your next academic library and asking a librarian/cataloger on-site.